# JavaFX CheckboxTreeItem: only handle the selected checkbox

Tags: javafx

Let's say I have a treeView similar to the one in the example. When I select the checkbox of a leaf (e.g. a1Item, a2Item), only one line will be printed in the console. When I select a parentItem (e.g. rootItem, aItem), the line of the item and the lines of the childItems will be printed, since the childItems will be automatically selected. 
 What I'm looking for is a way to only handle the selected checkbox, but keep the structure and the functionality (auto selection of childItems) of the treeView.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = createCheckBoxTreeItem("Root");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> aItem = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a1Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_1");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a11Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_1_1");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a12Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_1_2");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a111Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_1_1_1");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a2Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_2");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a21Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_2_1");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a211Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_2_1_1");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> a22Item = createCheckBoxTreeItem("A_2_2");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> bItem = createCheckBoxTreeItem("B");
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> cItem = createCheckBoxTreeItem("C");

        aItem.getChildren().addAll(a1Item, a2Item);

        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(aItem, bItem, cItem);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
        treeView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());

        aItem.setExpanded(true);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(treeView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> createCheckBoxTreeItem(String value) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(value);
        checkBoxTreeItem.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println(checkBoxTreeItem.getValue() + " - selected: " + newValue);
        });
        return checkBoxTreeItem;
    }
}
```

EDIT

I expanded the tree with 2 more level hoping this would help me to find a solution. When I select the rootItem/parentItem, I noticed that the output would be printed from the bottom(leaf) up to the selected item. But when I select e.g. the leaf A_1_1_1, A_1_1 would be printed first.

Comment: So I understand that you want the child items to continue to be selected when the parent item is clicked, but only the parentitem should be printed out?

Comment: I think you could say that. I run a service in my application, that uses the selection of the treeView to display the selected items and hide the rest of the items in the background. When I select/deselect a childItem, the service runs once (only one item changes it selection), but when I select/deselect the parentItem, the service restarts for every childItem, that has a new selection value. I mean It works right now, but I'm looking for a way, to bundle the changes and run the service once, to avoid unnecessary restarts.

Comment: Maybe go for something like onActionListener i think u can get the element that caused the ActionEvent there... Not sure just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

So to start off I don't expect you to implement this exact code in you application this is just to give you an idea of how to implement something like this. The way it works is by passing the parent to the function that is building the CheckBoxTreeItem(I understand you probably don't do this keep reading) so each listener has access to their own parent and by doing this we can check

- The current checkBoxTreeItem is selected
- The parent is not null meaning it is not the top of the tree
- The parent is not selected and it is not going to be selected by checking the current checkBoxTreeItem

Which allows us to build a decision on wether we should execute the necessary code.  The important part is that the listener on the code you wish to check the has access to the parent so it can figure out if it needs to fire.

Here is my solution

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem rootItem = buildNewCheckBoxTreeItem("Root", null);
        CheckBoxTreeItem aItem = buildNewCheckBoxTreeItem("A", rootItem);
        CheckBoxTreeItem a1Item = buildNewCheckBoxTreeItem("A_1", aItem);
        CheckBoxTreeItem a2Item = buildNewCheckBoxTreeItem("A_2", aItem);
        CheckBoxTreeItem bItem = buildNewCheckBoxTreeItem("B", rootItem);
        CheckBoxTreeItem cItem = buildNewCheckBoxTreeItem("C", rootItem);

        aItem.getChildren().addAll(a1Item, a2Item);

        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(aItem, bItem, cItem);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
        treeView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());

        aItem.setExpanded(true);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(treeView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private CheckBoxTreeItem buildNewCheckBoxTreeItem(String text, CheckBoxTreeItem parentCheckBoxTreeItem){
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(text);

        checkBoxTreeItem.selectedProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
            if(shouldFireListener(checkBoxTreeItem, parentCheckBoxTreeItem))
                System.out.println(checkBoxTreeItem.getValue());
        });

        return checkBoxTreeItem;
    }

    private boolean shouldFireListener(CheckBoxTreeItem checkBoxTreeItem, CheckBoxTreeItem parentCheckBoxTreeItem){
        if(checkBoxTreeItem.isSelected()){
            if(parentCheckBoxTreeItem!=null) {
                if (!parentCheckBoxTreeItem.isSelected() && !goingToBeSelected(parentCheckBoxTreeItem))
                    return true;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean goingToBeSelected(CheckBoxTreeItem parent){
        ArrayList<CheckBoxTreeItem> childrenArraylist = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object child : parent.getChildren()) {
            if(child instanceof CheckBoxTreeItem)
                childrenArraylist.add(((CheckBoxTreeItem) child));
        }

        return childrenArraylist.stream().allMatch(CheckBoxTreeItem::isSelected);
    }

}
```

EDIT: I have come across a bug where for example you select A_1 and A_2 A will select and fire but unchecking and rechecking either A_1 or A_2 will not re-fire A